# save bitmap from custom view that has an animation going on via the onDraw method

Tags: android, bitmap

So I have an animation that is being created by having a bunch of bitmaps drawn in the onDraw() method of a custom view. There is an update thread that calls a method in the custom view that changes the positions of the bitmaps to be drawn by the onDraw() method. What I would like to do is to save the bitmap created each time the update thread is finished so that i can create a gif from the bitmaps that i save.

I found the below code to save a png from a bitmap stored in memory to the SD card and that works with a stored bitmap but I'm having trouble with getDrawingCache():

```
public void saveView(){
    if(counter < 200){
        try {
            counter++;
            System.out.println("Counter : " + counter);
            File file = new File(path, "star"+counter+".png");
            file.delete();
            OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            buildDrawingCache();
            getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            destroyDrawingCache();
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this essentially does two things right now:

1) It takes about 50 images and saves them to the sd card. @ around 50 it causes the heap to get to large (i guess destroyDrawingCache() is unable to actually finish due to this is in a seperate thread)

2) In the pictures taken, you can see the scan lines from the buffer updating because I'm taking from a buffer that gets updated.

It would seem the getDrawingCache calls onDraw() as well which is why I can't have this on the UI thread in the onDraw itself.

If this is possible please help.

Comment: Is `saveView()` called on the UI thread?

Comment: no its in a new thread every time the onDraw is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call `getDrawingCache()` from outside the UI thread. That's why the bitmaps you get have partially updated scan lines. Call `saveView()` directly from `onDraw()`. Only the file operations may be run on separate threads after making a clone of the cached bitmap.

**Note:** You can call [`setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled%28boolean%29)? so that you don't have to call `buildDrawingCache()` and `destroyDrawingCache()`. Also if your device has hardware acceleration is turned on, you'll have to call `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`.

Another solution is to get the bitmap by calling [`View.draw(android.graphics.Canvas)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) on a new canvas that holds a blank bitmap.

Comment: when I run the code from the UI thread all i get is the same image over and over again, it never changes. Thats with setDrawingCacheEnabled(true) instead of the others.

Comment: using the View.draw(canvas) was the route I had to do. So basically I called saveView from the updating method. Inside saveview I made a temp bitmap and manually got the constructed bitmap from doing draw(canvas) then released and saved to sd.

Comment: I extended image switcher to capture screens while in animation, I did override onDraw() method, It's taking pictures as required but It doesn't drawing my view(just blinking some time) and not animating at all. I am wondering how it being able to capture images but not drawing it properly? Please help.